More results returned via API vs Front End
I am using the openFDA API to pull results for adverse events based on brand name and date range.
This is the URL that I am using:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.brand_name:*premierpro%20exofinfusion*+AND+date_received:[2019-01-01+TO+2024-12-01]&limit=1000
The intended filter is for data range: 2019-01-01 to 2024-12-01, brand name: premierpro exofinfusion.
The openFDA API returns 3 results ("MW5114259" "MW5115284" "MW5115902"), meanwhile the site returns a single record ("MW5115284").
If I look for two records missing in the front end query, they do appear to exist and would fit into the criteria. Is there something I'm misinterpreting or an API/Front-End functionality to be considered?
Thank you!
EDIT: I'm using the following site: accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm

Thank you for your question. Could you please let us know what tool you are using on the frontend. That will help us give you more accurate information.
Thank you!
Note: I'm a member of openFDA team.

Hello!
I'm using the following site: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm

We can’t easily explain the discrepancy, as we have no visibility into how the MAUDE Front-End search is implemented. It’s managed by a different team at the FDA and does not use the openFDA API for search, instead relying on their internal databases.
It seems, however, that the Front-End search applies more restrictive criteria for matching search terms. openFDA performs full-text search, identifying matches even when terms appear in a different order (e.g., "premierpro exofinfusion" matches "EXOFINFUSION PREMIERPRO MESH"), whereas the Front-End does not.
